# Can't import installed packages in python

Tags: software-installation, python, python-2.7, pip

I installed pip (`pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (python 2.7)). My python version is 2.7.

I installed `pygame` by `apt-get install python-pygame` and got a success message. But when I try to import it in `python`, getting the following message:

```
ashish@Ashish-Notebook:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jun  6 2016, 07:21:54) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame
>>>
```

Similarly, I installed Beautiful Soup by `pip install BeautifulSoup` and can't import it anywhere. Moreover when I again try to install, I get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): BeautifulSoup in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
ashish@Ashish-Notebook:~$
```

Moreover when i get a list of installed packages (by pip list). I can see pygame and beautifulsoup in that list.

Comment: It is very surprising to me that your Python cannot import `pygame` that is installed successfully according to you. Can you do `which python` and `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`?

Comment: which python
/usr/local/bin/python

python -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Comment: You installed your own Python?

Comment: Yes.I downloaded source and installed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when you install things with `sudo apt-get install` (or `sudo pip install`), they install to places in `/usr`, but the python you compiled from source got installed in `/usr/local`. The python you actually end up running when you type `python` at the prompt is the one you compiled (based on the output of the `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` command), and it can't find the python packages installed in the `/usr` directory. However, Ubuntu comes with python (both python 2 and python 3) already installed in the correct location, where it will find the installed packages. So a general recommendation is to try not to mix installation methods like this. Ubuntu has many software packages available through the official repositories which obviates the need to do much compiling yourself, and it's generally recommended to install software via apt when possible.

That said, for python packages (like Pygame and Beautiful Soup), things can get a bit more [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660601/how-to-do-python-package-management). Mixing `pip` and `apt-get` can cause troubles down the road, so one approach to keep things simple is to stick with just the system package manager. If you end up needing to use pip because the package manager doesn't have things you need (or up to date versions), it's better to work within [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use pip for all the python packages you need within that virtual environment.

To tell your system to find the default system python correctly (python 2, which is the default when you just call `python`), try rewriting the symlink that routes the `python` command at a prompt to the original destination:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Hopefully that should allow it to find the python packages you installed.